# iOS Volume only adjustable on Playback

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, volume, avaudiosession

Developing an iOS app which plays back audio messages in segments (not continuous playback). When the app is opened, I initialize the audio session with the following options.

```
func _initAudioSesh() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            try audioSession.setCategory(
                AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat,
                options: [
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth,
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP
                ]
            )
        } else {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
}
```

Then, when ready to playback audio, I grab focus using setActive(true) and release focus using setActive(false)

The issue I'm encountering is that in the app, the hardware volume buttons only work when audio is playing, otherwise, the buttons do nothing. I was able to hack around this by ALWAYS holding setActive(true), but that hack is ugly and causes other issues. Has anyone else experienced volume buttons not working/adjusting in-app, and only working when audio is actively being played?

As soon as I leave the app, audio adjustment works, as soon as I bring it back into focus, it stops working unless I begin to play audio.
I've tried messing with how & when I create the audio session, with no success.

Comment: did u try player.volume? while initializing the audioplayer? if no, why you want to adjust volume before ?

Comment: @HarjotSingh I think you're referring to volume or setVolume w/in AVAudioPlayer. I'm not trying to modify volume at all. Rather, I want the user to be able to use the hardware volume buttons, even if I'm not playing audio back in the app.

Comment: Yes, i am referring to that..Ok i understand your problem.

Comment: try to adjust the controls from Control Center aworkaround, like in playing music you can adjust the volume before playing.

Comment: Control Center does still show a volume controller, but this is another weird aspect of volume I have run into. That volume control does not affect my app's playback volume. For example, if during playback I turn volume all the way down, the control center will not mimic that change. (It's as if playback has its' own instance of volume, which is only accessible when playback is occuring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a result of a specific library we're using (react-native-system-settings), which has now been patched. If other users encounter issues, the fix seems to be around allowing UI to show in VolumeView. Otherwise, it doesn't allow the hardware buttons to affect volume.